# XML or Database? Asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, database

I have a webpage that I am trying to improve the efficiency on..

At the moment it has a front page that has snippets from my blog, classified section, directory, and latest forum topics.

At the moment everytime someone posts to the page it does the following:

- gets random 5 classified ad from sql database
- gets 5 random directory from online directory from sql database
- gets latest 5 posts from my forum via RSS
- gets latest blog poss via RSS

So to speed this up, I am creating a service, that will either update a SQL database, or a XML file every 10 minutes.. So there isn't so many database calls, webpage posts etc...

Now, I can either do this by writting a XML file or by writing a SQL database table...

Which is faster to access? Assuming that I have written both the most efficient way possible...

Comment: There are many approaches to caching which are much simpler than what you have proposed. Have a look at Microsoft's Enterprise Library Caching Block for example. Or, for a nice, simple implementation, just use the System.Web.Caching classes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx)

Comment: Profile, profile, profile: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Comment: Is it the database side of thing's that are being slow?  I'm pretty sure you could improve this without modifying the application

Comment: Agree with James Sulak.  3 quick hits to the DB to retrieve 5 items each (or 1 hit to retrieve 15, if you're clever with your SQL) doesn't seem like it would be an onerous performance hit.  Are you sure the DB is the bottleneck?  If so, there might be easier ways to improve it: ensure your table is indexed well; ensure you're using compilable/cachable queries (or use stored procs)...

Answer (score 0):

The speed issue it going to be largely determined by how you use the data. If you find yourself with an 8MB XML file that you only need 3 nodes from, I'm betting SQL would give you faster access to that data.
XML isn't really interchangeable with an RDBMS, but there are situations where it is as good or better. It all depends on your requirements.